# Unable to test alexa skill from developer console

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I started developing a skill on alexa developer console, have completed the checklist of items in build section, however i am still unable to enable testing for the skill, when i come on the test tab an error pops up saying :

```
Error retrieving skill metadata

There was an internal server error.

Sunday, March 17, 2019, 2:52 PM
```

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is due to a problem with your AWS developer account settings. Please check the permissions once.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, can you give an idea what permissions i should look for as i checked a lot on the alexa console settings and did not find anything, also checked on aws lambda console there is no setting to change there either, if you could elaborate it would be very helpful